# 'openInfoWindow' Causing an error on Google maps jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

I need some help with adding infoWindows on Google maps using jquery-ui-map v3

I am getting the Markers from a MySQL database and  i am attempting to add infowindow from the description of each location as stored in the data but i keep getting this error

**Uncaught no such method 'openInfoWindow' for gmap widget instance**

```
function initMap(container, pos, zoom) {
    $(container).gmap({
        'center': pos,
        'zoom': zoom,
        'zoomControlOptions': {
            'position': google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },
        'callback': function () {
            $.getJSON('backend/addmarkers.php', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, m) {
                    $(container).gmap('addMarker', {
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.latitude, m.longitude),
                        'icon': 'markers/' + m.cat_img,
                        draggable: false
                    }).click(function () {
                        $(container).gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                            'content': m.description
                        }, this)
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me out, in this thing running by monday. I have an academic presentation to make. 
Thanks

Comment: This works for me, which version do you use?

Comment: I am using v3-RC and i have followed the documentation at:  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code. Everything looks like its supposed to work well.

Comment: I am having the same error. What have you done to solve that ?